# the issue with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, linker-errors, duplicate-symbol

I'm having a problem about xcode. Please help me check this issue

This is my log from xcode

Ld /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Management-dbumnvnvxcjatwgwzoxobimmdmvo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Management.app/Management normal i386
    cd /Users/admin/Desktop/Project/Management
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Management-dbumnvnvxcjatwgwzoxobimmdmvo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Management-dbumnvnvxcjatwgwzoxobimmdmvo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Management-dbumnvnvxcjatwgwzoxobimmdmvo/Build/Intermediates/Management.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Management.build/Objects-normal/i386/Management.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security -framework CFNetwork -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -o /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Management-dbumnvnvxcjatwgwzoxobimmdmvo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Management.app/Management

duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_EditViewController._textfieldCategory in:
    /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Management-dbumnvnvxcjatwgwzoxobimmdmvo/Build/Intermediates/Management.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Management.build/Objects-normal/i386/AddTransactionViewController.o
    /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Management-dbumnvnvxcjatwgwzoxobimmdmvo/Build/Intermediates/Management.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Management.build/Objects-normal/i386/EditViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_EditViewController._labelType in:
    /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Management-dbumnvnvxcjatwgwzoxobimmdmvo/Build/Intermediates/Management.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Management.build/Objects-normal/i386/AddTransactionViewController.o
    /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Management-dbumnvnvxcjatwgwzoxobimmdmvo/Build/Intermediates/Management.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Management.build/Objects-normal/i386/EditViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_EditViewController._isType in:
    /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Management-dbumnvnvxcjatwgwzoxobimmdmvo/Build/Intermediates/Management.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Management.build/Objects-normal/i386/AddTransactionViewController.o
    /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Management-dbumnvnvxcjatwgwzoxobimmdmvo/Build/Intermediates/Management.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Management.build/Objects-normal/i386/EditViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_EditViewController._viewDate in:
    /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Management-dbumnvnvxcjatwgwzoxobimmdmvo/Build/Intermediates/Management.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Management.build/Objects-normal/i386/AddTransactionViewController.o
    /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Management-dbumnvnvxcjatwgwzoxobimmdmvo/Build/Intermediates/Management.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Management.build/Objects-normal/i386/EditViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_EditViewController._viewPicker in:
    /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Management-dbumnvnvxcjatwgwzoxobimmdmvo/Build/Intermediates/Management.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Management.build/Objects-normal/i386/AddTransactionViewController.o
    /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Management-dbumnvnvxcjatwgwzoxobimmdmvo/Build/Intermediates/Management.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Management.build/Objects-normal/i386/EditViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_EditViewController._datePicker in:
    /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Management-dbumnvnvxcjatwgwzoxobimmdmvo/Build/Intermediates/Management.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Management.build/Objects-normal/i386/AddTransactionViewController.o
    /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Management-dbumnvnvxcjatwgwzoxobimmdmvo/Build/Intermediates/Management.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Management.build/Objects-normal/i386/EditViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_EditViewController in:
    /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Management-dbumnvnvxcjatwgwzoxobimmdmvo/Build/Intermediates/Management.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Management.build/Objects-normal/i386/AddTransactionViewController.o
    /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Management-dbumnvnvxcjatwgwzoxobimmdmvo/Build/Intermediates/Management.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Management.build/Objects-normal/i386/EditViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_EditViewController in:
    /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Management-dbumnvnvxcjatwgwzoxobimmdmvo/Build/Intermediates/Management.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Management.build/Objects-normal/i386/AddTransactionViewController.o
    /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Management-dbumnvnvxcjatwgwzoxobimmdmvo/Build/Intermediates/Management.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Management.build/Objects-normal/i386/EditViewController.o
ld: 8 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I don't understand why reason. Everything is normal until I add 'Edit View Controller' to my app.  I have tried to delete 'Edit View Controller'. However it does not work. Can you please help me if you know solution for this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have something called a `AddTransactionViewController`.  In it, you're including storage for your `EditViewController`.  This may be because you're including a .m file instead of a .h.  Or, it might be because of something in `EditViewController.h` that shouldn't be there.

Check your include/import lines in `AddTransactionViewController.m` and `.h`.